# Centering long equations

Tags: equations, article

I have several long equations like the one below which bleed to the right margin of the document and lead to equation number being placed below them. Is there a way I can center them -- maybe by moving them a little inside the left margin? I tried using the solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/316904/189245) but it didn't work. I don't want to use smaller font size to handle this issue. Is there a way to handle them that I might not be aware of or is there some sort of 'best practice'?

[image]

Here is the MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.9cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amsthm, amssymb, epsfig}
\usepackage[scr=boondoxo,scrscaled=1.05]{mathalfa}
\begin{document}
The second part of impatient household's problem includes maximizing their utility, given their choice of loans. This can be written as 
\begin{equation}
\mathscr{L}_{t} = 
\mathbb{E}_{t}
\begin{Bmatrix}
    \sum_{t = 0}^{\infty}\left(\beta^{I}\right)^{t}
    \begin{bmatrix}
    \log\left(C_{m, t}^{I} - \gamma^{I}C_{m, t-1}^{I}\right) - \iota_{t}N_{m, t}^{I} + \varsigma_{t}\log H_{m, t}^{I} \\
    - \lambda_{m, t}^{I}
    \begin{bmatrix}
    C_{m, t}^{I} + \int_{0}^{1}R_{t-1}^{L}l_{mk, t-1}^{I}\mathrm{d}k - W_{t}^{I}N_{m, t}^{I} + Q_{t}^{H}\left(H_{m, t}^{I} - H_{m, t-1}^{I}\right) - x_{m, t}^{I} - \Phi_{t}^{I} - \Psi_{t}^{I}
    \end{bmatrix} \\
    - \mu_{m, t}^{I}
    \begin{bmatrix}
    R_{k, t}^{L}\int_{0}^{1}l_{mk, t}^{I}\mathrm{d}k - \int_{0}^{1}\theta_{k, t}\mathrm{d}k \mathbb{E}_{t}\left(Q_{t+1}^{H}H_{m, t}^{I}\right)
    \end{bmatrix} \\
    - \epsilon_{m, t}^{I}
    \begin{bmatrix}
    x_{m, t}^{I} - \left\{\int_{0}^{1}\left(l_{mk, t}^{I} - \gamma^{L}s_{k, t-1}^{I}\right)^{\frac{\xi - 1}{\xi}}\mathrm{d}k\right\}^{\frac{\xi}{\xi - 1}}
    \end{bmatrix} 
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{Bmatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You really ought to rephrase the equation instead. No-one want to read something like that.

Comment: @daleif Any suggestions on how to 'rephrase' the equation? In other words, what exactly would you have liked to see?

Comment: You could probably just move `- x_{m, t}^{I} - \Phi_{t}^{I} - \Psi_{t}^{I}` to the next line also don't use bmatrix for equations, that uses textstyle not displaystyle (see limits on `\sum` for example) but it would be far more readable if you split this up, giving names to the subterms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would stagger, rather than center.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.9cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage[scr=boondoxo,scrscaled=1.05]{mathalfa}

\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}

\begin{document}

The second part of impatient household's problem includes maximizing their utility, 
given their choice of loans. This can be written as 
\begin{equation}
\begin{gathered}
\mathscr{L}_{t} = 
\mathbb{E}_{t} = \sum_{t = 0}^{\infty}(\beta^{I})^{t} \biggl\{
  \begin{aligned}[t]
    & \log(C_{m, t}^{I} - \gamma^{I}C_{m, t-1}^{I}) 
      - \iota_{t}N_{m, t}^{I} + \varsigma_{t}\log H_{m, t}^{I}
    \\
    & - \lambda_{m, t}^{I} \biggl[
      \begin{aligned}[t]
        & C_{m, t}^{I} + \int_{0}^{1}R_{t-1}^{L}l_{mk, t-1}^{I}\diff k - W_{t}^{I}N_{m, t}^{I}
        \\
        &+ Q_{t}^{H}(H_{m, t}^{I} - H_{m, t-1}^{I}) - x_{m, t}^{I} - \Phi_{t}^{I} - \Psi_{t}^{I}
      \biggr]
      \end{aligned}
    \\
    & - \mu_{m, t}^{I} \biggl[
      R_{k, t}^{L}\int_{0}^{1}l_{mk, t}^{I}\diff k
      - \mathbb{E}_{t}(Q_{t+1}^{H}H_{m, t}^{I}) \int_{0}^{1}\theta_{k, t}\diff k 
      \biggr]
    \\
    & - \epsilon_{m, t}^{I} \biggl[
      x_{m, t}^{I} - \biggl(
        \int_{0}^{1}(l_{mk, t}^{I} - \gamma^{L}s_{k, t-1}^{I})^{\frac{\xi - 1}{\xi}}\diff k
      \biggr)^{\frac{\xi}{\xi - 1}}
  \biggr]\biggr\}
\end{aligned}
\end{gathered}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

The enclosing `gathered` places the equation number at the vertical center.

Note that all of your `\left` and `\right` were useless (apart from adding unwanted spacing).

I also added a better way to type in the differential.

[image]

The `epsfig` package only exists for back compatibility and should never be used in documents written in the last 25 years.

Comment: @daleif Yeah, right. I'll fix in a moment.